# SSAS Cube does not show a dimension

Tags: sql-server, ssas, analytics

I have recently started working with SSAS and just managed to create a cube in SSAS.

Nevertheless, there is one single dimension among all of them that does not appear when I'm browsing the cube.

In a more specific manner, the problem is that I have my fact table with its foreign keys pointing to the different dimensions:

```
|---------------------|
| FACT_TABLE          |
|---------------------|
| field1 (fk to dim1) |
| field2 (fk to dim2) |
| field3 (fk to dim3) |
| field4 (fk to dim3) |
| field5 (fk to dim3) |
|---------------------|
```

As you can see, field3, field4, and field5, point to the same dimension. But then, when I deploy the cube and browse it, field4 and field5 appear, but field3 does not!

I have already checked out, and the foreign keys in the source database are correct.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you add the dimension to a measure group? "Dimension Usage" tab in visual studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have the same dimension used multiple times, make sure you add the dimension to a measure group under 'Dimension Usage' tab in Cube design.

[image]

Comment: Yep, that did it. Although, it is strange to need to do that, since every single other field in the fact table got added 'automatically' (there are about some 15 fields and that is the only one that got away) when I used the cube creation wizard tool.